# Calculate 2 points in an outer circle given 2 points on an inner circle where lines joining both sets of points are horizontal

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Observing the diagram below, where the 2 circles have the same center point:

[image]

given the center point (X1,Y1), any radius S, and degrees D and E, it is possible to calculate Points (X2,Y2) and (X3,Y3), as follows:

```
var X2 = X1 + S * (cos(D * (PI / 180)));
var Y2 = Y1 + S * (sin(D * (PI / 180)));
var X3 = X1 + S * (cos(E * (PI / 180)));
var Y3 = Y1 + S * (sin(E * (PI / 180)));
```

So given that lines (X2,Y2),(X4,Y4) and (X3,Y3),(X5,Y5) are horizontal and both perpendicular to (X2,Y2),(X3,Y3), how do you calculate points (X4,Y4) and (X5,Y5) given any radius R?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write the equation for the outer circle:
$$C_2: (x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 = R^2$$

Now, just substitute $x$ with $x_2$ and $x_3$, as they clearly coincide with $x_4$ and $x_5$, and solve for $y$.

Comment: Hi Luigi, thanks for your suggestion. In the diagram I presented, X2 and X3 happen to coincide with X4 and X5 respectively. However, as the angles D and E can vary, that will not always be the case. doesn't the solution become more complex?